# Rails Model association with tabless Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to perform `has_one, belongs_to` association on a tableless model.

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one: b
end

class B < Tableless
   attr_accessor: b
end
```

I want to know whether this is possible in Rails

Answer (score 1):

Can you define an association on a tableless model? I'm going to answer 'no'. Associations use foreign keys to retrieve associated records and without a table to store that foreign key you cannot retrieve that record.

[Documentation about association methods](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods).